# Spark save and read Array[Byte] type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have serialize the object to `Array[Byte]` type, and save it to the parquet file as `StructField("byteArrayObject",ArrayType(ByteType), nullable = true)`. When I try to read it, using `row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("byteArrayObject")` there is an error:

> scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [B

Any one know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark deserializes array values as `WrappedArray`. Try the following:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import java.{lang => jl}

row
  .getAs[WrappedArray[jl.Byte]]("byteArrayObject")
  .map(_.byteValue)
  .array
```

Comment: look like it solve the WrappedArray isssue. still have 1 follow question, how about Byte. now it show like: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Byte; cannot be cast to [B. how can i convert it to scala's bytes in this example

Comment: @kailing I updated the answer.